# How to create a Wagtail redirect during testing

Tags: wagtail

I have a test case that relies on a wagtail redirect, but I cannot seem to get it to kick in:

```python
from django.test import TestCase
from wagtail.contrib.redirects.models import Redirect


class LocalizedRedirectTests(TestCase):
    def test_plain_redirect(self):
        """
        Test that the base redirect works.
        """
        Redirect.objects.create(
            old_path='/test',
            redirect_link='http://example.com'
        )
        response = self.client.get('/test')
        print(response)
```

This errors out during `self.client.get` because the redirect cannot be found in the list of url patterns:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_plain_redirect (testapp.wagtailcustomization.tests.LocalizedRedirectTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/dockerpythonvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/dockerpythonvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/app/dockerpythonvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 567, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLPattern 'robots.txt' [name='robots_file']>], ...snip..., 'path': 'test/'}
```

After which it throws a static files error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/testapp/wagtailcustomization/tests.py", line 14, in test_plain_redirect
    response = self.client.get('/test/', follow=True)
  
  ...snip...
  
  File "/testapp/wagtailpages/views.py", line 26, in custom404_view
    html = render(request, '404.html')

  ...snip...

  File "/app/dockerpythonvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 420, in stored_name
    raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '_css/main.compiled.css'
```

I also tried to cache it as `redirect = ...` and then using `redirect.save()`, but that had the same result, I also tried to explicitly add the site using `site = Site.objects.first()` and then passing that as `site=site` kwarg, but that also has the same result. I then tried the static `Redirect.add_redirect`, but even then: same result.

How do I create a redirect during testing, such that `self.client.get(...)` causes it to kick in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is two-fold: (1) use [override_settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#urlconf-configuration) to fix the static asset error, and (2) build the redirect as plain object and then `save()` it:

```python
from django.test import TestCase
from wagtail.contrib.redirects.models import Redirect
from django.test.utils import override_settings


# Safeguard against the fact that static assets and views might be hosted remotely,
# see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#urlconf-configuration
@override_settings(STATICFILES_STORAGE="django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage")
class LocalizedRedirectTests(TestCase):
    def test_plain_redirect(self):
        """
        Test that the base redirect works.
        """
        redirect = Redirect(old_path='/test', redirect_link='http://example.com')
        redirect.save()
        response = self.client.get('/test')
        ...
```

Additionally, if you have a multistage redirect (e.g. `/test` => `/`, and then due to i18n, another `/` => `/en/`) you'll need to follow the redirect and then check the resulting `response.redirect_chain`:

```python
        ...
        response = self.client.get('/test/', follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.redirect_chain, [
          ('/', 301),
          ('/en/', 302),
        ])
```

With the correct 301 or 302 value depending on whether it's a permanent or temporary redirect.